# Best way to pass ORDER BY as a parameter to a postgres function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rest

Assuming I have a postgres function like so (`...` ellipses are pseudocode)

```
create or replace function get_people (order_by varchar(64)[])
returns table (id bigint, age smallint, height smallint, weight smallint)
as $$
begin
select
    *
from
    person
order by
    ....
```

And assuming I want to allow my users to call this function like so through a REST API (pseudocode only, Ignore GET vs POST for the moment)

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: 'example.com/api/get_persons',
    data: JSON.stringify({order_by: ['weight ASC', 'height DESC', 'age ASC', 'id ASC']}),
...
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot use static SQL with parameters for that. Construct an SQL query string and run it with `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , that way the function is wide open to sql injection

Comment: @eshirvana I have a solution for that to create a type as an enum of possible order by options and then accept that as an array, but it's just so clunky because I imagine I would have to create a long string and then execute that

Comment: @eshirvana Of course, there is no way to avoid SQL injection with the proposed interface. Any solution involving dynamic SQL is clunky, but you got no better option. Using `format` reduces the clunkiness to the possible mininum.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a pram for each possible column you want to sort

```
SELECT
    *
from
    person
order by
case when 'weight asc' = ANY(orderbyenum) then weight end asc,
case when Paramwheightdesc then height end desc,
....
```

If you want it inside one array ( of enums for examples), I call it `orderbyparam orderbytype[]` which you pass to your proc:

```
SELECT
    *
from
    person
order by
case when 'weight asc' = ANY(orderbyparam) then weight end asc,
case when 'height desc' = ANY(orderbyparam) then height end desc,
....
```

Comment: Can you please add a function signature. This is a little unclear for me.